# Error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token {

Tags: c++, command, arguments, line

So I've been working on command line arguments in my Computer Science class and I've been getting this:

*error: unqualified-id before '{' token { 
{
^*

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with it and I can't wrap my head around there being an an error after my first int statement?? Here's the code. Any guidance would be much appreciated! I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to coding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> // for std::stringstream
#include <cstdlib> // for exit()

using namespace std;

double int_rate;
const double RULE72 = 72;
const double YDAYS = 365;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
{    
    printf("argc = %d", argc);

    double amount;
    double int_rate;
    int days;
    int years;

    cout << "What is the interest rate? ";

    cin >> int_rate;

    years = RULE72 / int_rate;

    cout << "Your money doubles in " << years << " years.";

    days = years * YDAYS;

    cout << "Your money doubles in " << days << " days." << endl;

    cout << "Amount you would like to see double. ";

    cin << amount;

    cout << "Money earned by day " << (amount * 2) / days << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trailing `;` at `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);` - remove it

Answer (score 3):

A more definitive answer to this problem would be that adding a semicolon ("*`;`*"), which is *treated as end-of-statement* (*except for the usage of **`\`***, **which is for splitting lines**) in *C++* and many other languages... and function names ended with these "*semi-colons*" are treated as a [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration)... So don't confuse it with [function definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition) which is what you want to do here...

Function declarations are the pre-defined function skeletons that do not have a body and **have** to be defined somewhere in the code... Or else the compiler will complain about the function not having a body...

Look here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]); // <- Semicolon
{
    // Some useful and useless code here... (but not going to work anyway, so...)
}
```

Here, the compiler says something like:

> "*Hey this function has a semicolon at its end, I know, it is a function declaration...*"

And when it reaches the next line, it is like:

> "*Huh!, where's the name of this function, **I know I got a semicolon at the previous line, so it couldn't be that!***"

And the compiler finally gives an error about the body not having a declaration... So, you have two options to do...

Either do something like this (Highly recommended by everyone)...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // <- Semicolon removed
{
    // Some useful and useless code here...
}
```

***Or:*** (Not recommended, but will not cause any problems)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]); // <- Semicolon! Meaning: Declaration!
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // Compiler says : Oh its the body (definition) of the declaration I read in the previous line...
{
    // Some useful and useless code here...
}
```

> **Note:** I'm sure the compiler would have pointed out to you which line is causing the error so you should try out some methods yourself because learning yourself gains you more experience than yearning for an answer...

Kind regards,

Ruks.

Comment: "which is treated as new line in C++"  the language does not care about line breaks. You can put all your code in a single line if you like.

Comment: @user463035818 No no no, I am trying to say that it is **treated** like a new-line (line break) in these languages and hence, real line-breaks only exist for the sake of readability...

Comment: and this is also not correct. I appreciate your answer trying to explain stuff in not so technical terms, but you need to be careful not to be incorrect. `;` is not treated as a line break.

Comment: @user463035818 Okay, I edited the answer...

Comment: it is also not a "end-of-line", `;` are rather unrelated to where a line ends. Consider `for(int i=0;i < 0;i++)` where are the line breaks? I guess you mean to say something like `;` ends a statement (though i have to admit that I am not even sure if this would be correct ;)

Comment: get an upvote for your patience :P

Comment: @user563035818 Thank you for clearing this *mis*conception of mine about semi-colons...

Answer (score 0):

As @StoryTeller said:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

This line is causing the problem. Remove `;` at the end of this line.

Comment: So I deleted the semi-colon at the end and I got even more errors than before such as: error: printf not declared in scope, and error no match for: 'operator<< (operand types are ::stdbasic_isstream<char> and d 'double') :/

Comment: is problem resolved? If not can you share new errors list?